# Swifty JSON Performance degradation with Swift3, XCode8, iOS10

Tags: swift, ios10, swifty-json

I have been using SwiftyJSON for JSON parsing in my app. I recently upgraded my app to Swift3 and am observing significant performance issues. I have tried to isolate the problem into a small project. I am considering switching to a different library or going native (but this a lot of work in my app), but would like to see if anyone in the community has observed a similar issue. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

The code below used to take subsecond in Swift2 but takes 15 secs in a release executable using Swift3:

```
func parseSampleJson() {
        let st = NSDate()

        let file:NSString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testJson", ofType: "json")! as NSString
        let jsonData:NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(file as String) as! NSData
        let json = JSON(data: jsonData as Data)

        let dataJson = json["data"]
        for (_, subJson): (String, JSON) in dataJson {
//            NSLog("Name = " + subJson["Name"].stringValue)
            let castes = subJson["Castes"]
            for (_, cn): (String, JSON) in castes {
//                NSLog("  Name = " + cn["Name"].stringValue)
            }
        }
        let et = NSDate()
        let timeTaken = et.timeIntervalSince(st as Date)
        NSLog("******* Time taken = \(timeTaken)")
    }
```

The full project is on github at https://github.com/good2best123/SwiftyJSONTest.

Comment: This looks like a problem still! do you find a solution yet ?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try upgrade to version `3.1.3`. The issue is resolved [there](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/pull/723)

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same behavior.  There appears to be a significant performance regression between SwiftyJSON 2.3.2/Swift 2.2 and SwiftyJSON 3.1.1/Swift 3.0.

The first thing I would try using an index to access the JSON data.

```
let dataJson = json["data"]
let n = dataJson.count

for djIndex in 0...n-1 {
  let subJson = dataJson[djIndex]
  let castes = subJson["Castes"]
  let castesCount = castes.count

//            NSLog("Name = " + subJson["Name"].stringValue)

  for cnIndex in 0..castesCount-1{
    let cn = castes[cnIndex]
    //                NSLog("  Name = " + cn["Name"].stringValue)
  }

}
```

From the testing I did on my code, it was clear that the JSON array parsing was there the CPU cycles were being used.

Caching any JSON property used more than once into a variable, while ugly, brought the performance of my Swift 3/SwiftJSON 3.1.1 code back to that of the original Swift 2.2/SwiftyJSON 2.3.2 code.

I hope this helps.